# php - mail with attachment file - message encrypted

Tags: php, email, chunks

I wrote this code for send an email with attachment in php from an html format:

```
<?php

if($_POST && isset($_FILES['file-upload'])){

    $from             = $_POST["email"]; 
    $rubinetteria     = 'info@domain.com'; 

    $nome             = filter_var($_POST["nome"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $email            = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $oggetto          = filter_var($_POST["oggetto"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 
    $compagnia        = filter_var($_POST["company"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $ruolo            = filter_var($_POST["ruolo"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $messaggio        = filter_var($_POST["messaggio"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

    $fileTmpName     = $_FILES['file-upload']['uploads'];
    $fileName        = $_FILES['file-upload']['name'];
    $fileSize        = $_FILES['file-upload']['size'];
    $fileType        = $_FILES['file-upload']['type'];
    $fileError       = $_FILES['file-upload']['error'];




    $handle = fopen($fileTmpName, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $fileSize);
    fclose($handle);
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

        $boundary = md5("sanwebe");

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "From:".$compagnia."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";


        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= "<b>Azienda: </b>" .$compagnia. "<br>";
        $body .= "<b>Nome e Cognome: </b>" .$nome. "<br>";
        $body .= "<b>Ruolo: </b>" .$ruolo. "<br>";
        $body .= "<br>". chunk_split(base64_encode($messaggio));


        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Type: $fileType; name=".$fileName."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= $encoded_content;

    $sentMail = @mail($rubinetteria, $oggetto, $body, $headers);

}


?>
```

The problem is that when I receive the e-mail, some of the message is encrypted.
I guess the problem is this line of code:

```
$body .= "<br>". chunk_split(base64_encode($messaggio));
```

I tried to subscribe this line with this one:

```
$body .= "<br>".$messaggio;
```

But in this case the message is not encrypted but there is no attachment file (the description confirms that the attachment is actually processed but not received)

Comment: What does "encrypted" mean? Do you have an example?

Comment: you should stop using php's `mail()` and look to phpmailer or swiftmailer

Comment: Your question is unclear. You will need to respond to comments or to [Martin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43726703/1415724).

Comment: @tadman since no code in the question encrypts any data, I take it that the OP only *thinks* the code looks encryted whereas a better term that could be used would be the code is `garbled` (which is the same but less ambiguous than "encrypted")

Comment: @Martin maybe their form is failing them and not using a valid enctype and post method, hard to say really. I voted as unclear to close.

Comment: actually, the more I look at the question, the more issues I see, but I can't be bothered keep adding new fixes to my answer.... But it's nice to see `base64_` is coming back into fashion...

Comment: `$headers .= "From:".$compagnia."\r\n";` that is incorrect. `mail()` expects an email address, not just a "company" name. Which is probably playing a big role in this.

Comment: It seems to be a case someone has copied the code from the [not great] walkthrough but without reading the walkthrough text... and yes good point, it may not be `multipart/form-data`

Comment: OP probably doesn't have CSRF on their form either, or any sort of repetition prevention on the above email sending script....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have two issues**

**1)**

```
 $fileTmpName     = $_FILES['file-upload']['uploads'];
```

This is incorrect, the `$_FILES` value you are referencing should be the temporary location of the uploaded file, that is not `[uploads]` but `[tmp_name]`, so replace the above code with:

```
 $fileTmpName     = $_FILES['file-upload']['tmp_name'];
```

---

**2)**

The second issue is the size of the file you've given to PHP to read `$fileSize` is *not* the full file, so the attachment is truncated and therefore displays improperly *(appearing "encrypted")*.

I've noticed PHP has numerous issues with the way it counts file sizes [possibly on certain platforms, I don't know]. In this instance it seems like the value given to the `fread` function is not the same byte-count as the actual complete file size, so the `mail` function only loads ~99% of the attachment, meaning the file is incomplete and so will look garbled (*"encrypted"*).

As [stated on the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php):

> If you just want to get the contents of a file into a string, use file_get_contents() as it has much better performance [than fread()].

so replace `$handle = fopen($fileTmpName, "r");`
`$content = fread($handle, $fileSize);` with:

```
 $content = file_get_contents($fileTmpName);
```

And this will catch the *whole* file size, rather than the arbitary amount defined by `$fileSize`.
 You should now have the complete file uploaded in your email.

---

**Bonus:**

As noted by `nogad`, you really should look up using [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) as `mail` function is fraught with similar little issues like the one here.

Comment: You ever heard of `word_chunk()` in php? I know it's a silly question, I had to ask. That answer down there isn't responding to a comment I left under it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can only think it's part of the addon library, "blowing". As in `blowing_chunks()`.

Comment: Sorry Martin; I don't follow. Unless that was a joke ;-) then I'd understand.

Comment: sorry yes, that was a [joke](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=blowing%20chunks). `:-|` . I want to go to bed but I need to wait for my virus scan to complete...

Comment: *hehe*, yeah kind of thought so ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- entirely on topic again, I have noted numerous instances of PHP not reading external file sizes correctly (esp with emails or with browser downloads) , but minimum discussion or litrature of this, from my short bursts of search engine searches for these things... is this something you're familiar with at all?

Comment: TBH Martin; I couldn't tell you for certain. From what I gather by what the OP wrote, seems that it's fine just as long as a certain part isn't encrypted. They've yet to respond to [tadman's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726518/php-mail-with-attachment-file-message-encrypted/43726703?noredirect=1#comment74496923_43726518), being *"What does "encrypted" mean? Do you have an example?"* - So, it's anybody's ballgame right now. I too didn't know what they meant and was going to post a comment to tadman's effect; he only beat me to it, so there was no sense for me to add another.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was reading that the OP simply thought the attachment *looked* encrypted because the code looked garble because the mailer was told the attachment was a certain size but the file attached was in fact a different size. This (above) is an issue I've found in my own work as we as various *un-specific* Q's (as in this one) on SO, but no clear liteature about PHP's reading of a filesize being, for instance, not the same as a mailer programs reading of a filesize when attaching a document to an email.